# Getting Javascript critical error in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, internet-explorer-11

I have a piece of code in my web application, When I include it, it works well in chrome but in IE11, it throws an critical error.

[image]

This is the code which is causing the error. If I comment it out, there is no error. That's why I'm pretty sure this code has some issue. and I couldn't find it.

JS Code

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea");
for(var el of inputs) {
   el.oldValue = el.value + el.checked;
}
```

debugger

[image]

even the debugger is pointing there. I don't know whats wrong in this code.

Answer (score 2):

`for ... of` is not supported by IE as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) in the Browser compatibility section

Comment: I guess I need to do in the classic way. Thanks @Francesco.